# JSON object in my RESTful web server

Tags: java, rest

How can I consume JSON object in my RESTful web server. How should be the client. I'm using Jersey server.
EX.

```
//BEAN
public class Student{
public String name;
}

//SERVER
@POST @Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/create")
public void create(Student s1) {
    System.out.println(s1.name);
}

//CLIENT
ClientConfig config1 = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client1 = Client.create(config1);
client1.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
WebResource service1 = client1.resource(getBaseURI());
Student s = new WSTestClient.Student();
s.name="POP";
service1.path("create").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(s);
```

Its not working...

Comment: any errors you get while running above code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in my client I have to add the following line to make the client post a JSON Object

```
config1.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE)
```

Have to add POJO Mapping to the ClientConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the REST web services development framework does the marshalling of json to objects. You need to consume a json form param in POST request and assign it to a java bean object. Here is a sample method contract for the same using Jersey framework:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response sampleRestMethod(@FormParam ("jsonStringParamName") YourCorrespondingJavaBean yourCorrespondingJavaBeanObj );
```

Follow this simple but really good tutorial to learn more about writing a RESTful service using jersey and json as the content type:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Comment: I have little bit confusion with your answer, in your method, YourCorrespondingJavaBean is a JSON String or if it should be JAVA bean means, 

    public Response sampleRestMethod(@FormParam ("jsonStringParamName") YourCorrespondingJavaBean oYourCorrespondingJavaBean);

Comment: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.WSTestClient$Student, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

This  is the exception I received from client...

Comment: @Pasupathi Have you annotatted your java bean and put all the relevant jars in your project. Let me find you a good tutorial to help with that.

Comment: @Pasupathi Updated the answer with the tutorial link.